# How can I replace a variable in one method from another method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working a project where I can add checkboxes but at first I make a textbox and then I press done and then the another button will replace that textbox with the value of that textbox.

When I have them in different methods the variable is not defined and when I put it in the same method it prints out in the console as twice the ids I need.

The first one below is the one that doubles the id - look at the console For both.

```js
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
  var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last"); // Getting the id of #buildyourownform and getting the last div 
  var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1; // Changing the Id 
  const fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
  fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
  // console.log(intId);

  var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
  var ftype = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"giannisCheckbox\" />");

  fieldWrapper.append(ftype);
  fieldWrapper.append(fName);
  $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);

  $("#doneBtn").click(function() {
    // $("#yourform").remove();
    $("#buildyourform div").each(function() {
      var id = "checkbox" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field", "");
      console.log(id);
      var label = $("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + $(this).find("input.fieldname").first().val() + "</label>");

      fName.replaceWith(label);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add" />
<input type="button" id="doneBtn" value="Done" />

<fieldset id="buildyourform"></fieldset>
```

```js
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
  var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last"); // Getting the id of #buildyourownform and getting the last div 
  var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1; // Changing the Id 
  const fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
  fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
  // console.log(intId);

  var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
  var ftype = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"giannisCheckbox\" />");

  fieldWrapper.append(ftype);
  fieldWrapper.append(fName);
  $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});

$("#doneBtn").click(function() {
  // $("#yourform").remove();
  $("#buildyourform div").each(function() {
    var id = "checkbox" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field", "");
    // console.log(id);
    var label = $("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + $(this).find("input.fieldname").first().val() + "</label>");

    fName.replaceWith(label);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add" />
  <input type="button" id="doneBtn" value="Done" />
  <fieldset id="buildyourform"></fieldset>
```

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Comment: @ruleboy21 My expected result is that when I press done, the textbox that is where you enter the value of the checkbox, will be replaced with the value of the textbox, but it won;t do that because 'fname' is not defined in the $("#doneBtn").click(function(),

Comment: @ruleboy21 What do you mean? I want there to be a textbox on the side of it so that way I can enter the text I want for it and then I press done and it replace it

Comment: Kindly check my answer if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
let $buildyourform = $("#buildyourform");

$("#addBtn").click(function() {
    let intId = $buildyourform.children().length + 1;
    $("#buildyourform").append(`
        <div class="fieldwrapper" id="field${intId}">
            <input type="checkbox" class="giannisCheckbox" />
            <input type="text" class="fieldname" />
        </div>
    `);
});

$("#doneBtn").click(function() {
    $buildyourform.children().each(function() {
        let $checkbox  = $(this).find('.giannisCheckbox');
        let $fieldname = $(this).find('.fieldname');
        let id         = "checkbox" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field", "");

        $checkbox.attr('id', id);
        $fieldname.replaceWith(`<label for="${id}">${$fieldname.val()}</label>`);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add" />
<input type="button" id="doneBtn" value="Done" />

<fieldset id="buildyourform"></fieldset>
```

Comment: This is really cool! Nicely done. I would create a variable for `$(this)` since you refer to it a few times in the click handler.

Comment: @HanletEscaño you're right. But I just leave it like that in small applications since the performance won't be noticeable. But again, you're right, it should always be cached once it's been used multiple times.

Comment: @ruleboy21 I had put it in my code and I am using vscode with google, and it keeps outputting in the console that it cant read unidentified with the replace, could it be the google browser or could it be something else and what would you change the "$(this)" to.

Comment: First, there is nothing wrong with `$(this)`. Secondly, can you show me a screenshot of what you have in vscode or you can put everything in a fiddle and share the link.

Comment: @ruleboy21 I figured out why I had put the <fieldset> tag over a couple of other checkboxes and divs and other things thank you thought

Comment: @GianniLombardo so everything is now working as expected?